# keynotfound on id decoding JSON

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

I'm getting the following error when trying to decode JSON.  What's odd is I've used similar code on other endpoints and no issue using UUID.

error:

***keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil) ("id").", underlyingError: nil))***

Here's my class

```
class Api: ObservableObject {
@State private var showingAlert = false

// completion handler for JSON Data
func getUserData(url: String, completion : @escaping ([RunClubsv2])->()){

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, _, err) in

        if err != nil{

            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        //decoding JSON

        do {

            let users = try JSONDecoder().decode([RunClubsv2].self, from: data!)
            print(users)
            //returning data
            completion(users)

        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
.resume()
}
```

Here's my UI code

```
    @State var runclubv2: [RunClubsv2] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if runclubv2.isEmpty{
                Text("damn it")
            }
            else {

                //display data
                List(runclubv2) { runclubv2 in
                    Text(runclubv2.name)
                }

            }

        }
        .onAppear{
            Api().getUserData(url: "<URL EndPoint>") { ([RunClubsv2]) in
                self.runclubv2 = self.runclubv2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the response data

```
[
    {
        "name": "Joggers for Lagers",
        "location": "Amor Artis Brewery, Fort Mill",
        "date": "6:30 PM",
        "category": "Monday"
    },
    {
        "name": "Old Armor Run Club",
        "location": "Kannapolis",
        "date": "6:00 PM",
        "category": "Monday"
    }
]
```

Comment: You have an `id` property in your `RunClubsv2` struct which probably needs to be optional :)

Comment: Create a CodingKey enum that contain only the properties you get from json (which does not include id I assume) so  `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  case name, location, date, category }`

Comment: You can't make UUID() an optional I thought.

Comment: @Robert you can generate `id` manually (if you need it) and not decoding it from the JSON because it does not exist there.

Comment: I am sorry, I am late. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403761/10758321

Answer (score 2):

Please read the JSON carefully. Where is the key `id`? That’s exactly what the error message says.

I guess your struct conforms to `Identifiable` with a *hard-coded* UUID. If so you have to add `CodingKeys` to exclude `id` from being decoded.

Comment: I don't understand.  I have a similar API call with a similar `struct` and I don't get this error and I don't have an `id` included.

Comment: The error is clear. The decoder tries to decode a key `id` which obviously doesn’t exist in the JSON. Therefore you have to add `CodingKeys`...

Comment: Yeah I can read :).  What I don't understand is how I can have two similar functions with similar struct's and one works and one doesn't.

Comment: Similar is not equal 

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `id` needs to be `optional`. So what happened in your code was that the `JSON_VALUE` was trying to write into the `id` key which obviously from what you show us is that there's no key named `id`.

I assumed that you might also face this following error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The error is very straightforward `No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").`

This can be solved.

Your current code must be:

```swift
struct RunClubsv2 {
    public var name :String
    public var location :String
    public var date :String
    public var category :String

}
```

The problem is from this line here `public var name :String`, which can avoid the error by adding a `?` after the `String` or `String?`. Which means you are making that `optional` or `nullable`.

Lastly, your updated code should be something like this:

```swift
struct RunClubsv2 {
    public var name :String?
    public var location :String
    public var date :String
    public var category :String

}
```